# Intel oneAPI dpcpp compiler with google test

Tags: intel, hpc, intel-oneapi, dpc++, oneapi

I'm kinda new to the world of Intel's HPC toolchain and I'm facing some troubles making even simple DPC++ application to work when gtest is used as a testing framework

This is the CMakeLists "structure" I'm following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "dpcpp")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O3 -fsycl")

# add executables 
# target linked libraries 
# ...

option(ENABLE_TESTS ON)
if(ENABLE_TESTS)
  FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    GIT_TAG release-1.11.0
  )
  set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

If I remove the last block, it compiles and runs as expected, otherwise I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at build/_deps/googletest-src/CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    dpcpp

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/u141905/foo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/u141905/foo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= /usr/bin/c++

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Please notice that dpcpp is correctly set, in fact I'm using Intel's devcloud platform.
Setting `CXX`to the output of `whereis dpcpp` produces the same error.
The only "workaround" (I doubt it is one though) I found is using clang++ instead (the version from Intel's llvm). Any help or suggestion is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: after some more attempts, I noticed that if I set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` just after fetching gtest, everything works fine. Anyway I don't understand why this happens and how can be properly fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the path for dpcpp binary for setting the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER instead of using"set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "dpcpp")". After adding the path("/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/dpcpp") to the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, you can run the program successfully.

Please find the below CMakeLists.txt for setting the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

```
project(foo)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin/dpcpp")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O3 -fsycl")
# add executables
# target linked libraries
# ...
set(ENABLE_TESTS ON)
include(FetchContent)
if(ENABLE_TESTS)
 FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG release-1.11.0
 )
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

Thanks & Regards,
Hemanth

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on devcloud. Actually It kinda "compiles forever", I don't know why

Answer (score -2):

Did you run the `source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64` script? I.e. is `dpcpp` on your path before running cmake?

Comment: This might as well be just comment than standalone answer

Comment: Yep. As I said, it works properly when I'm not trying to use gtest as testing framework. Also, all the examples on OneAPI-src work for me then I assume the compiler's path is in place